# Default context menu not black "settings"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Im running with `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`
why am i seeing this kind of context menu

[image]

and im unable to get the one which slides like below[image]

so that i can add icons to it and use it like a menu....

Comment: right now im having an actionbar, which is stuck at the bottom and wanted some animated one like the one seen in Gallery app...

Comment: atleast any pointers...

Comment: it depends on android version ... from ICS menus can or can not contain icons it depends where they are shown http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: but here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8iBIlVQCWM (at 0:11)the author is having the same ver. as i do....but not sure of minSdkVer...how is it possible...

Comment: no, his emulator works on Android 2.X not 4.X ...

Comment: awesome.. how did u get dat man....